# Publishing QGIS project on GeoServer?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms, layers

Is there a way to prepare a project on QGIS with many layers and to publish it under WMS service on GeoServer?

Comment: I think the way to go is http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/qgis_server_tutorial if you need directly publish projects. I don't think any other server is going to have that compatibility...

Comment: You could publish the data as a WMS using QGIS server, then use that WMS service as an input to GeoServer see http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html

Answer (score 2):

Now the best choice is GeoCat Bridge plugin for QGIS. It is already in the QGIS plugin repository. Here is the GitHub repository link:

[Geocat Bridge GitHub Repository](https://github.com/GeoCat/qgis-bridge-plugin)

The plugin provides two functions: publishing layer to GeoServer and publishing metadata to GeoNetwork. For GeoServer publishing, you have to do it layer by layer, not whole project. Here is the dialog for your information.

[image]

PS: GeoServer Explorer was excellent for this job and even more, but after Planet bought BoundlessGeo, they scrapped all the open-source projects. But the code is still there.
[Geoserver Explorer GitHub Repository](https://github.com/planetfederal/qgis-geoserver-plugin)
Anyone who is interested can relaunch the project for QGIS 3.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is the plugin "geoserver explorer" which communicate with geoserver through the REST API. You can publish layer and styles. Haven't tested it the last two years but last time i used it it was pretty useful.

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/geoserverexplorer/

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin is no longer maintained and does not work with the latest version of QGIS.

Answer (score -1):

If you have many layers to upload, you should look at the geoserver rest API - [see here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html)

You can also use the opengeo plugin - [see information](http://qgis.boundlessgeo.com/static/docs/quickstart.html)

However using shapefiles with geoserver isn't the best bet, it would be faster to use a DB (PostGis for instance) - [here is why !](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0309/files/9reasons.pdf)

Comment: I think this answer would become useful by including some summary information from each of the links that it contains.  I'm also not clear how your last link to "The Top Nine Reasons to Use a File Geodatabase" relates to the question, and the remainder of your answer.